# Text alignment function of NicEdit doesn't work on FireFox

Tags: nicedit

I found problem with NicEdit (Rich text editor)
when typing some text and click align button to align text. The text doesn't 
align only on FireFox and got this message on FireBug

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Component returned failure code:
>   0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
>   [nsIDOMNSHTMLDocument.execCommand]" 
>   nsresult: "0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS
>   frame ::
>   http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js
>   :: anonymous :: line 38"  data: no]
>   Line 0

Please could you help me to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: FYI, asking for "teh codez" isn't going to get you far. Can you please edit your question to be more specific, and provide some more information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the compressed code, go to line 37 and find this code:

Search for B.contentEditable

You will find an if condition exactly like this:

if (B.contentEditable || !!window.opera)

---

Replace it with this:

if ((B.contentEditable || !!window.opera) && navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox/3") == -1)

Comment: Thank you very very  much Maher El-Atawy, this is what I waiting for a long time. In my point, NicEdii suits my need  but the problem make me disappointed. 

Your help is my good news in this morning.

May God bless you. :)

Comment: I had the exact same issue and hadn't a clue on how to address it.  Your fix did the trick :)

Comment: I did what you said and it throws a new error: var B=$BK(this.elmFrame.contentWindow.document);   Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a useful answer. You should start doing answers more like this again.\

Answer (score 2):

The above answer will bring you in iFrame mode, which is rather slow. You better look here: http://web2.0goodies.com/blog/javascript/nicedit-firefox-center-and-right-align-bug-patch/. This wil actually 'fix' the FF bug.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However I've try the solution as follow the link. If It work, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this: `document.execCommand('StyleWithCSS', false, false);` ... right before your `execCommand(cmd, false, val)` command.  Around Line 576.

```
       nicCommand : function(cmd,args) {
          if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") <= 0) {
              //do not use for IE
              document.execCommand('StyleWithCSS', false, false);
          }
            document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
        }
```